# React clean-up function, what is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Regarding the official documentation clean-up function of react with useEffect help should be called only once and before component will be destroyed.
[image]

So regarding this information I made a component and put some code for example let it be the next one

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('didmount')
  return () => {
    console.log('will unmount2')
  }
})
```

I expect to see a several didmount consoles, depending on how many times I'm going to changes props of it and only one "will mount2" before I change my route, so component will be destroyed,
but actual result is next [image]

What I've just missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand or fully read the docs.

> Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect. In our example, this means a new subscription is created on every update.

Changing the props causes the component to rerender. Which in turn causes the clean-up function to be executed.

For your example this means that you should see serveral `didmount` and `will unmount2` in the console depending on how many times the component did rerender.

Comment: Seems you're right, thanks for your time...so there is no way to handle unmount event only now.....

Comment: There is. If you only want to handle the unmount, have a look at the second answer.

Comment: It doesn't work as I expect anyway, it fires 2 times even in second case, I've already read a lot of documentation, there is no way to have only 1 call with hooks as it was with componentWillUnmount

Answer (score 1):

hello Artem in your function you are missing the second param wich is the dependency array, without this array will cause an infinite loop ill suggest to try this

```js
// this will run exactly when the unmount component, not when the effects finishing running
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        console.log('unmount')
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already thought about it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Actually I was wrong and yes, your answer is absolutely correct, I've found a condition which destroyed component almost each first time app renders. 
That's why it runs twice and I thought it doesn't help.